# Change width and add a circular scroller to a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to increase the width of the scrollbar and add a circular scroller. Shall I use an image for the circle? I do not see any property or method of UIScrollView to change the width of the scroller

[image]

I tried the following:

```
UIScrollView *myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
myScroll.frame = self.view.bounds; //scroll view occupies full parent view!
//specify CGRect bounds in place of self.view.bounds to make it as a portion of parent view!

myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 800);   //scroll view size

myScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

myScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;    // to hide scroll indicators!

myScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES; //by default, it shows!

myScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;                 //say "NO" to disable scroll

[myScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
myScroll.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

[self.view addSubview:myScroll];
```

Comment: you cant change the width of the scroll bar. You can only add a custom view to the side of the scroll bar .

Comment: You can see this example to add a custom view to scroll bar. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460973/uiview-that-follows-uicollectionview-indicator/32462201#32462201

Comment: @Mr.T Can i increase width of that scroll bar for custom view?

Comment: yes you can do that!!!